# how to use get and set methods to set value of a property inside a class python 3.6

Tags: python-3.x, class, properties

```
class Employee:

    def __init__(self,Employee_Name,Hours_Worked,Hourly_Wage):
        self.Employee_Name = Employee_Name
        self.Hours_Worked = Hours_Worked
        self.Hourly_Wage = Hourly_Wage

    def displayName(self):
        print ("Employee Name :", Employee_Name)

    def displayHoursWorked(self):
        print ("Hours Worked :", Hours_Worked)

    def displayHourlyWage(self):
        print ("Hourly Wage :", Hourly_Wage)

    def Empname(self):

    def Emppay(self):
        if Hours_Worked <= 40:
            print("Employee Pay :",Hours_Worked * Hourly_Wage)
        if Hours_Worked > 40:
            print ("Employee Pay :",((Hours_Worked - 40) * (Hourly_Wage * 1.5)) + (Hourly_Wage * 40))

Employee_Name = str(input("Employee Name :"))
Hours_Worked = int(input("Hours Worked :"))
Hourly_Wage = float(input("Hourly Wage :")) 
myEmployee = Employee(Employee_Name,Hours_Worked,Hourly_Wage)
myEmployee.displayName()
myEmployee.displayHoursWorked()
myEmployee.displayHourlyWage()
myEmployee.Emppay()
myEmployee.Empname()
```

I'm stuck on a part of my homework assignment.

I'm tasked with creating a class named 'Employee',

(1)the constructor creates attributes Employee name, Hours worked, and Hourly wage.

(2)I need to use 'get' and 'set' methods to set the value of a property named 'Empname' that reflects the employee's name.

(3)I need a method named 'Emppay' that calculates the employee's weekly pay.

(4) I then need to ask the user to supply a name, hours worked and hourly pay and create 'myEmployee' object with my 'Employee' class. Using the 'myEmployee' object to print the name, hours worked and hourly pay. using the 'myEmployee' object call the 'Emppay' method to calculate weekly pay.

(5)Ask the user to change the employee name. using the 'Empname' property change the name to the new name and use the proper to print out the new name.

parts 2 and 5 are where i have no idea what i need to do and any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I adapted the [Python3 class property](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property) to your code:

Disclaimer: This is probably not the "pythonic" solution, but until other users offer an answer, I'll leave it here for your consideration. Hope it helps.

```
class Employee:
    def __init__(self,Employee_Name,Hours_Worked,Hourly_Wage):
        self.Employee_Name = Employee_Name
        self.Hours_Worked = Hours_Worked
        self.Hourly_Wage = Hourly_Wage

    def displayName(self):
        print ("Employee Name: ", self.Employee_Name)

    def displayHoursWorked(self):
        print ("Hours Worked: ", self.Hours_Worked)

    def displayHourlyWage(self):
        print ("Hourly Wage: ", self.Hourly_Wage)

    @property
    def Empname(self):
        print("getter of Empname called")
        return self.Employee_Name

    @Empname.setter
    def setEmpname(self, emp_name):
        print("setter of Empname called")
        self.Employee_Name = emp_name

    def Emppay(self):
        if self.Hours_Worked <= 40:
            print("Employee Pay :", self.Hours_Worked * self.Hourly_Wage)
        if self.Hours_Worked > 40:
            print ("Employee Pay :",((self.Hours_Worked - 40) * (self.Hourly_Wage * 1.5)) + (self.Hourly_Wage * 40))

name_1 = input("Employee Name: ")
hours_1 = int(input("Hours Worked: "))
hourly_wage_1 = float(input("Hourly Wage: ")) 
myEmployee = Employee(name_1,hours_1,hourly_wage_1)
myEmployee.displayName()
myEmployee.displayHoursWorked()
myEmployee.displayHourlyWage()
myEmployee.Emppay()

emp_name_change = input("What Employee name do you want to change? ")

if myEmployee.Employee_Name == emp_name_change:
    new_emp_name = input("Change {old_emp_name} to what new name? ".format(old_emp_name=emp_name_change))
    myEmployee.Employee_Name = new_emp_name
    print("{change_from}'s name changed to {change_to}".format(change_from=emp_name_change, change_to=new_emp_name))
else:
    print("No employee with name {change_from} exists. No names changed".format(change_from=emp_name_change))

print(myEmployee.Employee_Name)
```

Demos:

```
Employee Name: Jack
Hours Worked: 15
Hourly Wage: 10
Employee Name:  Jack
Hours Worked:  15
Hourly Wage:  10.0
Employee Pay : 150.0
What Employee name do you want to change? Steve
No employee with name Steve exists. No names changed
Jack

Employee Name: Steve
Hours Worked: 15
Hourly Wage: 10
Employee Name:  Steve
Hours Worked:  15
Hourly Wage:  10.0
Employee Pay : 150.0
What Employee name do you want to change? Steve
Change Steve to what new name? Jack
Steve's name changed to Jack
Jack
```